# Получение новой коллекции элементов

Tags: javascript, dom, коллекции

Необходимо получить все элементы, относящиеся к классу `video_row_info_name`:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('video_row_info_name');
```

В итоге получаем коллекцию элементов. Далее нужно создать коллекцию из уже созданной коллекции:

```
var b = a.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Но интерпретатор выдаёт сообщение об ошибке:

> getElementsByTagName('a') is not a function.

Как получить новую коллекцию элементов, если обратиться можно только к определённому элементу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить массив, состоящий из коллекций элементов `<a>`, можно, пробежав с помощью цикла по изначальной коллекции и получив коллекцию для каждого элемента отдельно:

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('video_row_info_name');
var links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    var b = a[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
    links.push(b);
}
console.log(links);
```

```html
<div class="video_row_info_name">
    <a href="#1"></a>
    <a href="#2"></a>
</div>
<div class="video_row_info_name">
    <a href="#3"></a>
    <a href="#4"></a>
</div>
```

Вариант с получением массива из `<a>` с помощью jQuery:

```js
var links = $('.video_row_info_name a').get();
console.log(links);
```

```html
<div class="video_row_info_name">
    <a href="#1"></a>
    <a href="#2"></a>
</div>
<div class="video_row_info_name">
    <a href="#3"></a>
    <a href="#4"></a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```